# Почему не срабатывает counter? при первом вызове в замыкании

Tags: javascript

В данном коде счетчика, первый лог выведет 1, не понимаю почему, ведь функция возвращает именно мутированное состояние переменной count;

```
var counter = (function() {
    var count = 1;
    return function() {
        return count++
    }
}())

console.log(counter())  // 1
```

Все равно что вот такая запись

```
var counter = (function() {
        var count = 1;
        return function() {
            return count
        }
    }())

    console.log(counter()) // 1
```

Почему в первой не возвращается 2?

Comment: Видимо потому, что вам нужно прочитать о постинкременте. Ну и заодно и преинкременте

Answer (score 1):

`return count++;` — сначала возвратит значение count, а уж затем увеличит его на единицу. Поэтому это нужно делать заранее.

```
var counter = (function() {
    var count = 1;
    return function() {
        count++;
        return count;
    }
}())

console.log(counter())
```